# Silverlight 5 UserControl does not appear in my grid

Tags: silverlight

I am using Silverlight 5.  I have a simple UserControl that looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GIS.VerticalDeformationGraphic"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" >
    <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" MinHeight="400" >
        <Canvas Width="65" Height="450">
            <Rectangle Canvas.Left="5" Canvas.Top="10" Width="15" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="DarkRed" Offset="0.0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.2" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.4" />
                        <GradientStop Color="LightGreen" Offset="0.5" />
                        <GradientStop Color="LightBlue" Offset="0.6" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.8" />
                        <GradientStop Color="DarkBlue" Offset="1.0" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

I have a reference in my xaml page like this:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GIS"
```

and I attempt to place the user control in a grid cell, like this:

```
<local:VerticalDeformationGraphic Grid.Column="0" />
```

If I take the ViewBox that is in the UserControl and simply paste the whole thing into the grid, the only change I have to make is to assign the Grid.Column to the ViewBox and it works.  What am I missing that keeps the UserControl from appearing as a UserControl?

This is exactly how I am using it in my page:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--<sdk:Label Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,1,0,1"
               Content="A Graphic Goes Here">
    </sdk:Label>-->
    <local:VerticalDeformationGraphic Grid.Column="0" Height="450" Width="65" />
```

Note that the Label worked before I commented it out.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code into a user control and it works as expected.  Can you maybe post a simple example of how you're using the control?

Comment: I have added an example to the question.

Comment: What's the issue exactly?  Is there a compiler error?  Runtime error?  Or is the app running and the user control simply not appearing?

Comment: I am not seeing any compiler or runtime errors.  The control just does not appear.  There is not even any space allocated for it, unless I provide the Width parameter on the control, in which case then I have a certain amount of empty space.  When inline, the code works perfectly, so it seems that the missing piece must be in the  UserControl or in the way I am invoking it.  Looks pretty simple to me... :)

Answer (score 1):

The code-behind must call InitializeComponent( ).  When I right-click the project and select Add / New Item / Silverlight, I do not have an option for Silverlight UserControl... so I had just added a xaml file.

Comment: Silverlight is frustrating sometimes.  Nice catch.